# Embedded Classes in Spring/Rest/MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, spring-mongo

I have an Address class embedded within an Organization class. What is happening is that the ID field of the address class is not getting populated when I post an address to the organization.

I know...in MongoDB sub documents don't need their ID. Well I want them to have one just in case I decide to de-couple them or delete a particular address. I did create an id field for the Address, but clueless as to why its not getting populated.

```
public class Organization {

@Id private String id;

private String name;
private String organizationType;
private String email;   
private String programmingBoardEmail;
private String website;
private Date springBooking;
private Date fallBooking;
private String facebook;
private String twitter;
private String parentID;
private Address address;
private List<Phone> phones;
private List<String> activities;
```

---

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.geo.Point;

public class Address {

@Id private String id;

private String firstLine;
private String secondLine;
private String city;
private String state;
private String zip;
private Point location;
```

'

Do I need to do something special to do this? Can I call that ID generator on my own when I initialize an address class?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just assign ObjectId yourself when you create new Address

```
address._id = new ObjectId();
```

Comment: Damn I repied too quickly. Its not understanding what ObjectId() is. Is there an import I am missing?